# Override theme styles with plugin styles

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, enqueue

I am writing a custom WordPress plugin, I am using the OceanWP Theme with Elementor, and am trying to enqueue/register Bootstrap 4.5 styles/scripts as well as my own custom styles/scripts.

However, OceanWP's styles are still taking precedence being used instead of my styles/scripts.

Currently, I am trying to over ride the themes assets by upping the priority in the add_action hook but am not having any luck.

I am trying to display a custom multi-part form and display it on a page using a shortcode.

```
public function __construct()
        {
            //set dirpath
            $this->_dirpath = dirname(__FILE__);

            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cmmc_styles'), 9999);
            add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'cmmc_scripts'));

            add_shortcode("sme-cmmc-form", array($this, "displayCmmcForm"));
        }

        public function cmmc_scripts()
        {

            ///wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all');
            wp_enqueue_script('popper_js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);
            wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

            wp_enqueue_script('cmmc_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/app.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
            //wp_enqueue_style('custom_styles', plugins_url('/assets/css/styles.css', __FILE__));
            
        }

        public function cmmc_styles() {

                wp_register_style('bootstrap_css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
                wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css');
                wp_enqueue_style('custom_styles', plugins_url('/assets/css/styles.css', __FILE__));

        }
```

Can someone please tell me how I could possibly over ride the themes styles, even if it is just for this plugin, or dequeue the styles for this single page temporarily?

EDIT: to add in the enqueued styles and scripts from the theme

```
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'theme_css' ) );

            // Load his file in last.
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'custom_style_css' ), 9999 );

            // Remove Customizer CSS script from Front-end.
            add_action( 'init', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'remove_customizer_custom_css' ) );

            // Load theme js.
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'theme_js' ) );

/**
     * Load front-end scripts
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public static function theme_css() {

        // Define dir.
        $dir           = OCEANWP_CSS_DIR_URI;
        $theme_version = OCEANWP_THEME_VERSION;

        // Remove font awesome style from plugins.
        wp_deregister_style( 'font-awesome' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'fontawesome' );

        // Load font awesome style.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', OCEANWP_THEME_URI . '/assets/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.min.css', false, '5.11.2' );

        // Register simple line icons style.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'simple-line-icons', $dir . 'third/simple-line-icons.min.css', false, '2.4.0' );

        // Register the lightbox style.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup', $dir . 'third/magnific-popup.min.css', false, '1.0.0' );

        // Register the slick style.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', $dir . 'third/slick.min.css', false, '1.6.0' );

        // Main Style.css File.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'oceanwp-style', $dir . 'style.min.css', false, $theme_version );

        // Register hamburgers buttons to easily use them.
        wp_register_style( 'oceanwp-hamburgers', $dir . 'third/hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css', false, $theme_version );

        // Register hamburgers buttons styles.
        $hamburgers = oceanwp_hamburgers_styles();
        foreach ( $hamburgers as $class => $name ) {
            wp_register_style( 'oceanwp-' . $class . '', $dir . 'third/hamburgers/types/' . $class . '.css', false, $theme_version );
        }

        // Get mobile menu icon style.
        $mobileMenu = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_mobile_menu_open_hamburger', 'default' );

        // Enqueue mobile menu icon style.
        if ( ! empty( $mobileMenu ) && 'default' !== $mobileMenu ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'oceanwp-hamburgers' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'oceanwp-' . $mobileMenu . '' );
        }

        // If Vertical header style.
        if ( 'vertical' === oceanwp_header_style() ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'oceanwp-hamburgers' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'oceanwp-spin' );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns all js needed for the front-end
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public static function theme_js() {

        // Get js directory uri.
        $dir = OCEANWP_JS_DIR_URI;

        // Get current theme version.
        $theme_version = OCEANWP_THEME_VERSION;

        // Get localized array.
        $localize_array = self::localize_array();

        // Comment reply.
        if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        }

        // Add images loaded.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded' );

        // Register nicescroll script to use it in some extensions.
        wp_register_script( 'nicescroll', $dir . 'third/nicescroll.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

        // Enqueue nicescroll script if vertical header style.
        if ( 'vertical' === oceanwp_header_style() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'nicescroll' );
        }

        // Register Infinite Scroll script.
        wp_register_script( 'infinitescroll', $dir . 'third/infinitescroll.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

        // WooCommerce scripts.
        if ( OCEANWP_WOOCOMMERCE_ACTIVE
            && 'yes' !== get_theme_mod( 'ocean_woo_remove_custom_features', 'no' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'oceanwp-woocommerce', $dir . 'third/woo/woo-scripts.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );
        }

        // Load the lightbox scripts.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup', $dir . 'third/magnific-popup.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'oceanwp-lightbox', $dir . 'third/lightbox.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

        // Load minified js.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'oceanwp-main', $dir . 'main.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

        // Localize array.
        wp_localize_script( 'oceanwp-main', 'oceanwpLocalize', $localize_array );

    }
```

Comment: We need to see the enqueue code for the styles that you are trying to override also please.

Comment: @FluffyKitten added them in

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how to dequeue the scripts w/o having a look at the theme source code. Anyways usually you just need to wait until the theme has done it's job, hook into wp and them remove the styles searching for their handles name. Something like this:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','alter_styles');
function alter_styles(){
    wp_dequeue_style();
    wp_dequeue_script();
}
```

Instead, speaking of your code, first question is: are you sure you load that code at the right time, in the right place or does it get executed at all?
You can do something like:

```
add_action('template_redirect','my_template_redirect');
function my_template_redirect(){
    if (is_page('your_page')){
        // Load class / do stuff with scripts/styles
    }
}
```

to be sure and execute the code just for that particular page

Comment: You mean code errors or you didn't manage to achieve the expected results? You can even try to use enqueue by passing the dependence parameters but you always need to know the parent theme handle name

Comment: No, neither of those worked for me in the sense that they did not achieve desired results

Comment: If it's just a matter of few rules just overwrite them with more specific CSS rule (copy the parent theme one and add one level of CSS specificity). If that doesn't work then try by using enqueue_styles dependencies parameter and using the handle name got from theme_css parent function. Those are the ways to achieve what you are looking for. The rest is all about execution order with WordPress code or doing thing properly. W/o seeing it all its quite difficult but I guess we gave you the answers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same css class names, in your css file just add !important before the semi-colon to the attributes you want to force.

Comment: They are using input type selectors in order to target the elements directly that way. Not sure how to over ride that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can get your stylesheets to load after other stylesheets are loaded. You have already tried a few ways, but **the parent theme is a very high priority of `9999` so you need to use an even  higher one** or it won't work.

**1. Priority**

You are using priority `9999` in your `add_action`, but if you look at the parent theme, it uses:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( 'OCEANWP_Theme_Class', 'custom_style_css' ), 9999 );
```

The priority for **your code isn't actually higher than the parent theme**, so you need to go higher again, e.g.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cmmc_styles'), 10000);
```

---

**2. Dequeuing** (Note, you need to match the values used when it was enqueued)

You said dequeuing didn't work for you, but note that when you dequeue a style the priority determines when it runs - just like when you are enqueuing - so you need to use a higher priority than what was used when it was enqueued. It also must use the same hook (or a later one).

As we saw above, you need to do this with **a priority higher than the `9999` they were enqueued with**, e.g.

```
function dequeue_oceanwp_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style('oceanwp-style');
    wp_deregister_style('oceanwp-style'); 
}
/* Now call this function with a higher priority than 9999 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_oceanwp_styles', 10000);
```

---

**3. Dependencies**

If that doesn't work you can set up dependencies between the styles to force the order.

When you use either [`wp_register_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) or [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), you can specify dependencies for the stylesheet you are registering/enqueuing - i.e. the other stylesheets needed by your stylesheet. This means that the **stylesheet you are registering won't get loaded until *after* the ones it depends on.**

To do this, you pass an array of the *handles* for the stylesheets that must be loaded first, e.g.

```
// create an array with the handles of the stylesheets you want to load before yours
$dependencies = array('oceanwp-style', 'oceanwp-hamburgers', /* etc. */ ); 
/* Noew pass this in as the dependencies for your stylesheets */
wp_register_style('bootstrap_css', 
    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
    $dependencies, /* array of dependencies */
    NULL, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css');

/* Add bootstrap to the dependencies, if your custom_styles needs it */
$dependencies[] = 'bootstrap_css'; 

wp_enqueue_style('custom_styles', 
    plugins_url('/assets/css/styles.css', __FILE__),
    $dependencies, /* array of dependencies */
);
```